# Export a very large attribute table (1,5 M rows) into Excel spreadsheet QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, excel

I have a very large shapefile containing rainfall data for South Africa. Each point is a single rainfall that lasted for 1 hour. I have 1,5 million points. For further analysis, I need to export it into Excel.

When I try to save the shapefile using "Save feature as" either into an xlsx file or a CSV file, the first 1550 rows are omitted, the file starts at row 1551, and the last 200'000 rows are omitted as well. Any insight on what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Could you split the data in two and then try exporting them and merge them after?

Comment: if you have ms access available, you could open the dbf file there and export to excel

Comment: Excel can import .dbf files directly.

Comment: Please describe your further analysis. Maybe SQL would be the better choice, so you wouldn't have to export anything.

Comment: @Erik, in excel; I must find first quartile Q1 and third quartile Q3 of my rainfall data, and Q1 and Q3 of the distance to the shore of these rainfall points (I have the info already). Once I have these quartiles, I create a release rate matrix, based on the rainfall and the distance to shore. It's a conditional formula with basically: if rainfall1 is < Q1 (rainfall data) and distance to coast < Q1 (distance to coast data), assign release rate 1 etc. I just can't see how my computer would handle this inside QGIS, just deleting 1 field takes 5 min and makes the software almost crash.

Comment: First step with huge datasets in QGIS is for me nowadays to convert them to geopackage. The problem with excel is, that it tops out at 1.05 million rows - so you wont be able to load your data completely anyways.

Comment: @Erik, Thanks for your input. I was reading another post where I think it is you that talks about geopackage for large files. I do the same now and it has been very helpful.

Comment: Depending on the version of Excel, it might support a million (2^20) rows, but older releases are limited to [64k](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/65,536#In_computing) (2^16). This more of a task for a database, though Access could do in a pinch.